# how to implement calender concept in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calendar

in my application i need to implement calendar concept.i found this site ***http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=244&cpage=1#comment-827*** and i need to get the current month,year value but i cant get them can any help i solving this problem will be appreciated.
in this i can get only currentmonth,currentyear value(i.e 6-5-2011)today date

Comment: Please explain what u want.You are saying "i need to get the current month,year value" & again u say "in this i can get only currentmonth,currentyear value(i.e 6-5-2011)today date ".whatas the diff

Comment: hi swastik i can get the value of current month,current year.if the user goes to previous year(2010)at that time i cant get the value of that year.why because the value which i am getting current value only .so please provide me solution for it if u know methood in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these projects -

https://github.com/voidparadox/Si-Calendar

https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary